# Fail2Ban with disabled password authentication

Tags: networking, ssh, raspberry-pi, fail2ban

I am tinkering with my RPI4 and I got into Fail2ban currently. I disabled Password authentication on my SSH server and imported keys for Public key auth. For some reason I am still getting occasional email notifications about banned IPs. Here is a example of log of such ban.

```
Lines containing failures of 116.105.77.108
Jul  4 11:39:14 pollux sshd[11482]: Connection from 116.105.77.108 port 54936 on 192.168.3.18 port 32
Jul  4 11:39:15 pollux sshd[11482]: Invalid user admin from 116.105.77.108 port 54936
Jul  4 11:39:16 pollux sshd[11482]: Connection closed by invalid user admin 116.105.77.108 port 54936 [preauth]
Jul  4 11:39:41 pollux sshd[11487]: Connection from 116.105.77.108 port 46524 on 192.168.3.18 port 32
Jul  4 11:39:43 pollux sshd[11487]: Invalid user user from 116.105.77.108 port 46524
Jul  4 11:39:43 pollux sshd[11487]: Connection closed by invalid user user 116.105.77.108 port 46524 [preauth]
Jul  4 11:39:52 pollux sshd[11492]: Connection from 116.105.77.108 port 47862 on 192.168.3.18 port 32
Jul  4 11:39:53 pollux sshd[11492]: Invalid user ubnt from 116.105.77.108 port 47862
Jul  4 11:39:54 pollux sshd[11492]: Connection closed by invalid user ubnt 116.105.77.108 port 47862 [preauth]
```

I have read something about ***preauth*** and ***grace time*** but I still dont fully understand, why bans are happening. There are also logs which show about 30 or 40 times more tries for authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you disabled password auth, there is still  the possibility to proved a wron (i.e. inexistant) **username** - this is what happended in your log fragment.

In parctice it means: Someone tried and failed.